# On finding the number of homomorphisms from $G$ to $G_1\oplus \cdots \oplus G_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

How shall I establish that the number of homomorphisms from the group $G$ to $G_1\oplus G_2\oplus \cdots G_n$ is same as $h_1h_2\cdots h_n$ where $h_i$ is the number of homomorphisms from $G$ to $G_i$ ? Here $G, G_1, G_2, \cdots, G_n$ are all groups.

Comment: I can only say that it's not the same, for example consider homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z_2} $ to $\mathbb{Z_2}\times \mathbb{Z_2}$

Comment: @Belgi: There are four morphisms $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$, and $4 = 2 \times 2$ where $2$ is the number of morphisms $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$...

Comment: why aren't they the same?

Comment: The cross product have three elements of order two giving us one more homomorphisms, which is also an isomorphism

Comment: @Belgi: I'm sorry but don't understand what you are trying to say. $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2$ has three elements of order two, yes, but what is the "one more homomorphism" you are talking about? Isomorphism between what and what?

Comment: @Idrissi I'm sorry that I was unclear, I'm writing from a mobile phone so it's difficult to write math. I hope this will be more clear:define the following isomorphism $h$:$h(0)=(0,0),h(1)=(1,1)$

Comment: @Belgi: This is not an isomorphism... $(1,0)$ is not in the image! To make everything clear (I think there's a miscommunication somewhere), the four homomorphisms I'm talking about map $1$ respectively to $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$, and they all map $0$ to $(0,0)$. None of these are isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant that it's isomorphic to its image. You're also right about the four homomorphisms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finite direct sum is a product. By the universal property of products, a homomorphism $G \to G_1 \times \dots \times G_n$ is uniquely determined by its projections $G \to G_i$ and vice-versa. In other words, there is a bijection $$\hom(G, G_1 \times \dots \times G_n) \cong \hom(G, G_1) \times \dots \times \hom(G, G_n)$$
and the cardinality of this last set is $h_1 \dots h_n$.

Comment: Please see my comment to the post

Comment: @Najib Idrissi Sorry, how does a bijection between $\hom(G, G_1 \times \dots \times G_n)$ and $\hom(G, G_1) \times \dots \times \hom(G, G_n)$ suggest that $G \to G_1 \times \dots \times G_n$ is uniquely determined by its projections?

Comment: @Brofessor Because that's how the bijection is defined. It sends a map $f : G \to G_1 \times \dots \times G_n$ to $(p_1 \circ f, \dots, p_n \circ f)$ where $p_i : G_1 \times \dots \times G_n \to G_i$ is the projection.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi since im pretty new to this, is there somewhere where i could read about how the bijection is defined in this context? or perhaps, something i could search up?

Comment: @Brofessor I defined the bijection in my comment, what else did you want to know?